# C code gives different output

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve a problem in Code Forces — http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/680/B. I've already solved it locally, but when I upload it to Code Forces it gives different output.

Currently, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int q, pos;
    scanf("%i %i", &q, &pos);
    int cities[q];
    int criminal_count = 0;
    //the greatest distance is naturally the number of cities
    int criminals_by_dist[q];
    for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i)
        criminals_by_dist[i] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i)
        scanf("%i", &cities[i]);

    //now we have the cites, lets count
    //first the centre
    if (cities[pos - 1] > 0)
        criminals_by_dist[0]++;
    int l = 0, r = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < q; ++i)
    {
        //count how many on the left of current position
        //first check if it is not out of range
        l = pos - i;
        if (l >= 0)
            criminals_by_dist[i] += cities[l - 1];
        //same with the right
        //first check if it is not out of range
        r = pos + i;
        if (r < q)
            criminals_by_dist[i] += cities[r - 1];
    }

    //count how many criminals can be secured in a particular city
    //the centre is always confirmed because there is only one centre
    criminal_count += criminals_by_dist[0];
    int current = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < q; ++i)
    {
        current = criminals_by_dist[i];
        if ((current == 2 || (pos - i - 1 >= 0 != pos + i - 1 < q)))
            criminal_count += current;
    }
    printf("%i", criminal_count);
    return 0;
}
```

In my console, I enter the following input:

```
6 3
1 1 1 0 1 0
```

and the output is:

```
3
```

However, in codeforces, the following happens:

Input

```
6 3
1 1 1 0 1 0
```

Output

```
1998776724
```

Answer

```
3
```

It is all the same code. Why does this happen?

Comment: Please explain what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: `if(l >= 0)criminals_by_dist[i]+=cities[l-1];` is wrong. What if `l == 0`? What is then `l - 1`? Same thing with `r` later in the same loop.

Comment: `if(l >= 0)criminals_by_dist[i]+=cities[l-1];` can lead to out of bound access.

Comment: I'm not against mixing variable declarations with executable statements. But not in one line!

Comment: When two different systems take the same source code and input data and generate different answers, it normally means you've got 'undefined behaviour' (UB).  Your code is doing something that it should not be doing, and the systems treat the UB differently.  That's perfectly permissible; a system can do anything when you invoke UB.  One of the commonest causes of UB is accessing out of bounds in an array.  Another common cause is using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: It worked!!! thank you! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm isn't quite correct.

At this line

```
l = pos - i;
```

`l` becomes smaller than 1 at some point and therefore you access cities out of bounds which is undefined behaviour.

Modify like this:

```
 #include <assert.h>
 ...
//count how many on the left of current position
//first check if it is not out of range
l = pos - i;
assert(l > 0);                                // <<< add this line
if (l >= 0)
  criminals_by_dist[i] += cities[l - 1];
```

Run your program again and you'll see what happens.